# How to get the SMTP Adress of the sender outlook / Exchange

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am trying to get the SMTP Adress of the sender in an outlook plugin.
This worked as expected when I follow the examples from MSDN 
like [this one here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184647.aspx):

```
private void GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(Outlook.MailItem mail)
{
    const string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";
    Outlook.Recipients recips = mail.Recipients;
    foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in recips)
    {
        Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = recip.PropertyAccessor;
        string smtpAddress =
            pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS).ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(recip.Name + " SMTP=" + smtpAddress);
    }
}
```

But since some time (some weeks) the reference schema at

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E
```

can not be resolved anymore.
**Errormessage**:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E Property unknown or ca not be found.
```

If I try the URL in a browser I get:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

All examples I can find (for office 2013 and above) are pointing to ressources at http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/SOMETHING

I also could not find any info in forums or oon MSDN that this moved or changed ..

Is anyone else running into this ?
Is ther a known solution or workaroud.

Answer (score 1):

`http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E` is not a link, it the actual DASL property name that the `PropertyAccessor` object expects. The format is different for the fixed and named MAPI properties (e.g. `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/85100003`). 
You can look at the MAPI properties and their DASL names in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

Also keep in mind that you should not expect any particular MAPI property to be present - they are not guaranteed to be present and you must expect and handle errors returned by the `PropertyAccessor` object.

In your particular case, you can are not checking the SMTP address of a sender, you are working wit the message recipients. For the recipients, check if the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property is there. If not, open the adders entry (`Recipient.AddressEntry`) and check for that property from the `AddressEntry`. You can also check for the presence of the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` multivalued property (an array is returned). You can so try `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` (be prepared to handle errors and nulls).
Once again, take a look at the message with OutlookSpy to see which property is present.